# Raise a custom exception on import

Tags: python, exception

Short question: I have a module with objects. How can I do that if someone imports an object from my module, my specified exception is raised?

What I want to do: I write an architectural framework. A class for output depends on `jinja2` external library. I want the framework to be usable without this dependency as well. In the package's `__init__.py` I write conditional import of my class `RenderLaTeX` (if jinja2 is available, the class is imported, otherwise not).

The problem with this approach is that I have some code which uses this class `RenderLaTeX`, but when I run it on a fresh setup, I receive an error like `Import error: no class RenderLaTeX could be imported from output`. This error is pretty unexpected and ununderstandable before I recall that `jinja2` must be installed beforehand.

I thought about this solution: if the class is not available, `__init__.py` can create a string with this name. If a user tries to instantiate this object with the usual class constructor, they'll get a more meaningful error. Unfortunately, simple import

`from output import RenderLaTeX`

won't raise an error in this case.

What would you suggest, hopefully with the description of benefits and drawbacks?

Important UPD: I package my classes in modules and import them to the module via `__init__.py`, so that I import 'from lena.flow import ReadROOTFile', rather than 'from lena.flow.read_root_file import ReadROOTFile.'

Comment: I also found that one can customize imports in Python, but I'm not sure it's worth and reliable to do that in my case. https://blog.ffledgling.com/python-imports-i.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a year of thinking, the solution appeared.

First of all, I think that this is pretty meaningless to overwrite an exception's type. The only good way would be to add a useful message for a missing import.

Second, I think that the syntax

```
from framework.renderers import MyRenderer
```

is really better than

```
from framework.renderers.my_renderer import MyRenderer
```

because it hides implementation details and requires less code from user (I updated my question to reflect that). For the former syntax to work, I have to import *MyRenderer* in `__init__.py` in the module.

Now, in `my_renderer.py` I would usually import third-party packages with

```
import huge_specific_library
```

in the header. This syntax is required by [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports). However, this would make the whole *framework.renderers* module depend on *huge_specific_library*.

The solution for that is to violate PEP 8 and import the library inside the class itself:

```
class MyRenderer():

    def __init__(self):
        import huge_specific_library
        # ... use that...
```

Here you can catch the exception if that is important, change its message, etc. There is another benefit for that: there exist guides how to reduce import time, and they propose this solution (I read them a long time ago and forgot). Large modules require some time to be loaded. If you follow PEP 8 Style Guide (I still think that you usually should), this may lead to large delays just to make all imports to your program, not having done anything useful yet.

The only caveat is this: if you import the library in *__init__*, you should also import that to other class methods that use it, otherwise it won't be visible there.

For those who still doubt, I must add that since Python imports are cached, this doesn't affect performance if your method that uses import is not called too often.

Answer (score 1):

When Python imports a module all of the code inside the file from which you are importing is executed.

If your `RenderLaTeX` class is therefore placed into a seperate file you can freely add logic which would prevent it from being imported (or run) if required dependencies are missing.

For example:

```py
try:
    import somethingidonthave
except ImportError:
    raise Exception('You need this module!')

class RenderLaTeX(object):
    pass
```

You can also add any custom message you want to the exception to better describe the error. This should work in both Python2 and Python3.

Comment: Thank you. As I understand, this works only when I import from file `output.render_latex` not from the package `output`?

Comment: This should work regardless of how it is imported. If you import from `output` then first the code in the `output/__init__.py` file is executed. If there are any exceptions in this file - for example from trying to import from your module that contains `RenderLaTeX` then this exception will propagate back to where you imported from the `output` package. Hopefully this makes sense?

Comment: if I import `RenderLaTeX` to `output.__init.py__`, then if it fails, the whole output package will not be available?

Comment: I think I found the solution. Anyway thanks for your answer! I think that my question was not very good, but hope that it's finally solved.